# Distributed A/B-like testing with Locust

Tags: performance-testing, distributed, locust

I need to compare network latency for 2 clients half the globe away from each other and visualize the response time history for each location the request comes from side-by-side. I've been researching load and performance testing tools and found Locust to be very convenient. Is there a way I can achieve my goal with Locust in a quick/standard/non-hacky way?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you mean you need 2 clients in different locations running the same task to compare or 2 clients in 2 different locations running 2 different tasks, Locust can handle either of those scenarios.

Check out the [Tasks](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#tasks) section of the documentation for details about how to write tasks. You can write a single task that does both of what you need, two different tasks that are randomly selected for each user that starts, write two tasks and have them be weighted in their randomness (including making one weighted at 0 so it's never run, effectively turning one task off so only the other one is run at that time), and many other options. Which method is best will depend on exactly what you need and how you want to do it. It may take some experimentation to determine what's best.

As for running in multiple locations, you can run the test separately in different places and compare results, or Locust can run [distributed](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html) so you can have workers in multiple locations running at the same time. You may also want to look at using [Docker](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-docker.html), which in some ways can make running in different locations easier if you use AWS, Azure, GCP or whatever other cloud provider to spin up instances to run on.